# Vue js multiselect edit form not showing data

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have used a vue multiselect in my laravel app like this ...

```
<coupon-form :action="'{{ $coupon->resource_url }}'" :data="{{ $coupon->toJson() }}"
                    inline-template>

<form class="form-horizontal form-edit" method="post" @submit.prevent="onSubmit" 
:action="this.action" novalidate>

<multiselect v-model="selected" :options="options" :loading="isLoading" :internal-search="false" 
:multiple="true" :close-on-select="false" :hide-selected="true" name="books[]" @search-change="getData" 
label="name" track-by="id"></multiselect>
</form>

</coupon-form>
```

and its vue file is like this

```
import AppForm from '../app-components/Form/AppForm';

Vue.component('coupon-form', {
    mixins: [AppForm],
    data: function() {
        return {
            form: {
                name:  '' ,
                description:  '' ,
                valid_from:  '' ,
                valid_till:  '' ,
                discount:  '' ,
                enabled:  false,
                books: [],
            },
            isLoading: false,
            options: [],
            selected: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getData(query){
            this.isLoading = true;
            axios.post('/admin/books/find/'+query)
            .then((response) => {
                this.options = response.data;
                this.isLoading = false;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.isLoading = false;
            });
        },
    },
    watch: {
        selected (newValues) {
             this.form.books = newValues.map(obj => obj.id);
        }
    }
});
```

While storing the form the multiselect works but in editing it doesnot shows the selected data Can Any one tell why ??? and how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `:value` attribute in order to set the default selected values not the `v-model`.

The `v-model` for vue-multiselect is basically a copy it handles internally. Should not be used to set an option manually. Use `:value` for that.